# How to search the process using built-in web camera in MacBook air

Tags: macos, webcam

I using MacBook Air Mid 2012. Now LED of buit-in web camera lighting green.
How to search the process using built-in web camera ?

Comment: So -- to summarize -- you want to know which process (or app) has your Macintosh camera open?

Comment: Yes I want to know which process is accessing camera.